# LED matrix 7x10

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, led-matrix, 74hc595, cd4017

I am trying to assemble a 7 x 10 LED single-color matrix using 2 74HC595's for the 10 columns and a CD4017 for the 7 rows. Now obviously I am only going to use a total of 10 pins of the 74HC595 instead of the 16. With the other pins not being used, am I going to have problems?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are unused outputs. No problems expected because of leaving outputs unused.